NameError: uninitialized constant Mysql2::Client::LONG_PASSWORD
i just started working on a project it has rails 3.2.22.5 and using mysql2 gem version 0.3.11, i am setting up the project on docker desktop
i am getting the following error:
NameError: uninitialized constant Mysql2::Client::LONG_PASSWORD
i have tried all versions of mysql2 0.3.xx series each of them gives me the same error
when i switch to a version 0.4 or later i get a new issue related to activerecord-mysql2-adapter
how can i fix the Mysql2::Client::LONG_PASSWORD error without needing to upgrade the mysql2 gem?


Downgrade MySQL/MariaDB to a 5 version
Or manually patch the mysql2 gem to remove the LONG_PASSWORD reference (client.rb file)

